# What happens to "lost" stack objects?

Tags: c++, object, stack

Say `Pokemon` is a class. Consider this snippet:

```
Pokemon Eve(4,3); //call to constructor, creating first object on the stack
Eve=Pokemon(3,5); //call to constructor again, creating a second object on the stack
```

Both objects are created on the stack. After the second line executes, the first object (with parameters 4,3) can no longer be accessed. What happens to it? What is the jargon used to describe this process? Garbage collection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what is happening. The object originally created as `Eve` isn't 'lost' after the second line. In fact, it is still the same object afterwards (by which I mean it still has the same memory address). The second line *assigns* a different value to the object by calling the assignment operator on the object `Eve`. The parameter passed to the assignment operator is the temporary object created by `Pokemon(3,5)`.

It is the said temporary object - `Pokemon(3,5)` which is destroyed after the second line. Its destruction is not 'garbage collection' or even a heap deallocation, as it is a stack object in the first place and thus doesn't require such.

I think you're thinking about this in terms of Java/C# or similar managed languages, that only have object references and not direct objects. In C++ with the code above you're dealing with objects directly. To see something equivalent to what you have in mind, consider this:

```
Pokemon* Eve = new Pokemon(4,3); 
Eve=new Pokemon(3,5);
```

Here we're using pointers and the heap, rather than the stack. In this case, the second line really does 'lose' the original object, because it is the pointer that is reassigned. This is *sort of* similar to what happens in Java/C# with just normal assignment. The difference is, of course, that C++ doesn't have any garbage collector so in the above the original object is truly lost in the sense of being a memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

It's called "the assignment operator", or "=".

The second object is the temporary object, not the first one. After it is constructed, the first object's assignment operator is invoked, to assign the value of the second object to the first object.

After that the second object's destructor is invoked, and the second object gets destroyed. Where it goes? To the great bit bucket in the sky. It's gone.

Answer (score 1):

The objects are not created on the heap, but directly on the stack, so no space is lost (i.e., there's no allocated space that becomes unreachable) -- the assignment simply reuses the memory allocated by the initialization of `Eve`.

*Edited: More careful wording around the "overwriting" contention.*

Comment: I wouldn't say that the allocated space is "simply overwritten". The C++ assignment operator may do multiple things before overwriting anything. It may not overwrite anything at all depending on the implementation of `operator=()`!

Comment: That's precisely what happens with the default implementation, and, arguably, that's what any sane override should do, as far as assignment semantics goes.  Granted, the question provides an excellent opportunity for plugging-in an in-depth rant on special operators in C++, but I'm very much in doubt that the OP called for that.

Comment: Quite true, that's why I didn't downvote. It depends entirely what happens in the OP's `Pokemon` class though. The most obvious reason to override `operator=()` is to do deep copies of pointers, which does not just "simply overwrite" the class contents. My comment was more just to point out that we can't necessarily make assumptions about OP's `Pokemon` class and make blanket statements.